# Confusion on wording of an exercise about Krull dimension.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> Let $k$ be a field, $f(x,y)\in k[x,y]$ be any polynomial, and consider the variable $x'=x-y^n$. Show that $k[x,y]=k[x',y]$, and that if $n$ is sufficiently large, then as a polynomial in $x'$ and $y$, $f$ is a scalar times a monic polynomial in $y$. Deduce that $k[x,y]/f$ is integral over its subring $k[x']$. Use this to show that dim $k[x,y]=2$.

This is Exercise 9.2(a) from Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*, but I don't quite understand it. I don't know why if $n$ is sufficiently large, then $f$ can be written as scalar times a monic in $y$ for any polynomial $f$. Also, I don't think $k[x']$ can always be a subring of $k[x,y]/f$, like when we take $f=y$, as we can easily check, the previous statement doesn't hold in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required to show that if $n$ is sufficiently large, then as a polynomial in $x'$ and $y$, $f$ is (almost) monic in $y$, and this is easy enough: when replace $x$ by $x-y^n$ in a monomial $x^iy^j$ the only monomial in $y$ is $y^{ni+j}$. This could interfere with other monomials in $y$ of $f$, but for $n$ large enough it actually doesn't, and we get a power of $y$ times a non-zero element of $k$. Anyway, when consider the ideal generated by $f$ we may assume that $f$ is monic as a polynomial in $y$.

Then we have $k[x']\subset k[x',y]=k[x,y]\to k[x,y]/(f)$. You can check that the composition of these two morphisms is injective. In particular, $\dim k[x,y]/(f)=\dim k[x']=1$.

Comment: What if $f=x+y^n$ this turns out to be $x$ in $k[x’,y]$ and doesn’t contain monomial in $y$.         And also do you mean the last quotient ring is injective for any $f\in k[x,y]$ ?

Comment: $n$ is not fixed in this question, so your example is irrelevant. In particular, one can choose $x'=x$ if $f$ is already monic in $y$. Then, a quotient ring can't be injective, but a morphism can, and in this case it doesn't matter what $f$ is.

Comment: Thanks. I see. Now I understand that the question actually asks one to find such $n$, for a given $f$ to make it a monic times some $k$.Then the $k[x',y]/(f)$ contains $k[x']$ and is integral over it follows easily.